# 2d text focuses on camera but get rotate 180 when camera rotates around the object

Tags: unity-game-engine, mindmapping, mindmap

I have created multiple gameobjects in the scene with parent child relationship. When I move the camera with a joystick it moves around the node in an orbit. but when the camera moves vertically the 2D text on Node gameobject which focuses the camera by `LookAround()`, it rotates 180 degrees. Which is in the opposite direction.

Comment: Could you provide more details? What is this LookAround function, as i'm sure it is not a built in unity function. Maybe show us the code?

Comment: transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, -Vector3.right, variableJoystick.Vertical * 200 * Time.deltaTime);

Comment: I wrongly mention Lookaround(), it is RotateAround()

Comment: Same code using for Horizontal movement

Comment: 'transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(-Camera.main.transform.forward); // This one for cam rotation'

and this code used for 2d text to focus and look towards camera

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code in the question!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Transform.LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html). Get a reference to the camera's transform, for example with `Transform mainCam = Camera.main.transform` then in the update function of your 2D text or any object you want to look at the camera use `transform.LookAt(mainCam);`

Comment: this.transform.LookAt(target.transform); 

>> also tried this. Same it rotates the 2d element clockwise and give not exact result